# Form on CSS + output to .txt – problem with calling a PHP function

Tags: php, css, forms, function, output

I have a form on CSS + part that sends data from text fields to the server-located file `data.txt`
Whenever I click on "submit" button, nothing goes on.
I see this as a clear problem with a calling a PHP script

```
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
    $data=$_POST['textdata'];
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pure CSS Steps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Pure <strong>CSS</strong> Steps</h1>
        <p>... a sassy "Step By Step" process.</p>
    </header>

    <section>
        <article>

            <form method="post" class="pure-steps" >
                <input type="radio" name="steps" class="pure-steps_radio" id="step-0" checked="">
                <input type="radio" name="steps" class="pure-steps_radio" id="step-1">
                <input type="radio" name="steps" class="pure-steps_radio" id="step-2">

                <div class="pure-steps_group">
                    <ol>
                        <li class="pure-steps_group-step">
                            <header>
                                <h2 class="pure-steps_group-step_legend">Welcome</h2>
                                <p class="pure-steps_group-step_item">You are about to form the form.</p>
                                <p class="pure-steps_group-step_item"></p>
                            </header>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pure-steps_group-step">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend class="pure-steps_group-step_legend">Grab a tour</legend>

                                <p class="pure-steps_group-step_item flexy-item flexy-column reverse">
                                    <input name="textdata" type="text" placeholder="Type your email here" value="" id="input_email" >
                                    <label for="input_email">Email</label>
                                </p>

                                <p class="pure-steps_group-step_item flexy-item flexy-column reverse">
                                    <input  type="text" placeholder="Type your nick here" value="" id="input_nick">
                                    <label for="input_nick">Name</label>
                                </p>

                                <p class="pure-steps_group-step_item flexy-item flexy-column reverse">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your nick here" value="" id="input_nick">
                                    <label for="input_nick">Phone</label>
                                </p>
                            </fieldset>
                        </li>

                        <li class="pure-steps_group-step flexy-item">
                            <div class="pure-steps_preload">
                                <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
                                    <path d="M31.8,3.6c-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.9-1.2C30.4,2,29.7,1.8,29,1.9c-0.6,0.1-1.2,0.4-1.6,1l-8.5,11.2l0,0l-7.2,9.5l-7.1-9.4 c-0.5-0.7-1.3-1-2.1-1c-0.5,0-1,0.2-1.4,0.5c-0.5,0.4-0.9,1-1,1.7s0.1,1.2,0.5,1.8l9.1,12.1l0,0c0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4 c0.4,0.3,0.9,0.5,1.4,0.5c0.8,0,1.6-0.3,2.1-1L22.1,18l0,0l9.1-12.1C32,5.2,32.1,4.4,31.8,3.6z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>

                    <ol class="pure-steps_group-triggers">
                        <li class="pure-steps_group-triggers_item">
                            <label for="step-0">Restart</label>
                        </li>

                        <li class="pure-steps_group-triggers_item">
                            <label for="step-1">Grab a tour</label>
                        </li>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit">

                        <li class="pure-steps_group-triggers_item">
                            <label type="submit" name="submit" for="step-2">Jump in</label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>

                </div>
                <br>
                <label for="step-0">Restart</label>
            </form>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

The file is in the place.
What seems to be the problem here? 
I see this as a problem with calling a PHP – there is no place to call it.
Any suggestions where is the problem located?

Comment: Did you forget the `action` on your form tag?

Comment: What have you tried to spot the error? What exactly does happen after submitting the form?

Comment: @NicoHaase – nothing happens. And this is why I am looking for a clue.

Comment: Are you running any JS when you submit the form? Like posting it using Ajax or similar? Also, you have two text-inputs with the same ID `input_nick`. Id's needs to be unique within the document. Also, both those fields are missing the `name`-attribute which are required for them to be submitted.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No, this is the only code I have. https://codepen.io/artoha/pen/LaOYaQ - here is how it looks like. With name-attributes that you've correctly suggested + correct text-inputs.

Comment: Try adding a print statement in the block and see if it prints

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't client side and executes once on every request.

You could make the form point to itself which will make the page reload but this time with `$_POST` data.

```
<form method="post" class="pure-steps" action="thisPage.php" >
```

Comment: Omitting the action tag (like the OP has it) or leaving it empty will also make the form post to itself, so this shouldn't really make any difference.